# How to access MasterPage1 method in another ContentPage with MasterPage2 in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have `Page1.aspx` which has `MasterPage1.master` as its `MasterPage` and `Page2.aspx` which has `MasterPage2.master` as its `MasterPage`. I am showing `Page2.aspx` page in `iframe` (which is in `Page1.aspx`) `Page2.aspx` displays some items in `ListView`. After adding item to Cart(`MyCartUserControl` in `MasterPage1.master`) i want to call the Method say 'MyMethod()' which is in `MasterPage1.master.` in `Page2.aspx`

**In Page2.aspx:**

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Sales/MasterPage1.master" %>
```

**In Page2.aspx.cs**

```
protected void UpdateShoppingCart()
    {
        Sales_MasterPage1 master = (Sales_MasterPage1)this.Master;
        master.BindCart();
    }
```

I know the above code will not work using `'this'`. What is replaceable to `'this'` keyword?

Help Appreciated!

Comment: create new instance of the **master**. have a look at my answer. hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code :

```
protected void UpdateShoppingCart()
{
   Sales_MasterPage1 master = new Sales_MasterPage1();
   master.BindCart();
}
```

Comment: sorry @SpiderCode this will not work. as BindCart() method call another method that is in ShoppingCartControl.ascx where it will get null for Repeater in ShoppingCart User control. the DataTable has rows but the Repeater that we are binding it shows NULL.

Comment: For that user control you should create generic method which can return only data table.

Comment: All the controls on ShoppingCart shows NULL when accessing method  that is in ShoppingCart.ascx.cs :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the access modifier.

You might need to make it a `public` method because `protected` wont let you access it outside of that master class

```
public static void UpdateShoppingCart()
{
   Sales_MasterPage1 master = new Sales_MasterPage1();
   master.BindCart();
}
```

to call it from anywhere you can do:

```
Sales_MasterPage1.UpdateShoppingCart()
```